# How to USE the SOLR api over ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Am in process of analyzing the steps involved in migrating SOLR to ELasticsearch. While doing so we came across a plugin call Mock SOLR API.
The plugin which is found SOLR-MOCK (https://github.com/mattweber/elasticsearch-mocksolrplugin). But am not able to install this Could anyone please help with the steps or suggest some alternate ways to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: As you can see the latest supported ES version is 0.20.2 and the plugin was last updated 4 years ago, so it's veeeeeeeeery old. I doubt that you'll be able to install that plugin since so much as changed in the interval.

Comment: Oh is there any other plugin available to use the SOLR API against  the ElasticSearch ?

Comment: Check this project: https://github.com/o19s/solr-to-es

Comment: Thanks @Val but that is for migrating the SOLR index data to ElasticSearch.  But am looking something like where I can use the solrJ API's on ElasticSearch for querying the data from ELasticSearch whichever got migrated from SOLR -to-ES.